# How to post two form with single submit click

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I had two forms

1. login form
2. Registration form

login form has the username and password fields and registration form consists controls for registration like username, city, country, etc.,

3. Also, I have some hidden controls like

```html
<input type="hidden" name="ctrl1" />
<input type="hidden" name="ctrl2" />
<input type="hidden" name="ctrl3" />
<input type="hidden" name="ctrl4" />
```

Which is dynamically generated using PHP Code.

What I want is, When the user click login form's submit or the registration form's submit, the hidden controls data should also be Posted.

Comment: You should consider adding the hidden controls to the form being submitted. The only way to post two forms is via JavaScript; you'll wind up having to fire an AJAX request before your main form is submitted, and things will break terribly if the user has JS disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert the hidden inputs into both forms when you generate the page:

```
<form id='form1' action='' method='post'>

<input type='hidden' name='h1' value='v1' />
<input type='hidden' name='h2' value='v2' />
<input type='hidden' name='h3' value='v3' />

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit Form 1' />
</form>

<form id='form2' action='' method='post'>

<input type='hidden' name='h1' value='v1' />
<input type='hidden' name='h2' value='v2' />
<input type='hidden' name='h3' value='v3' />

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit Form 2' />

</form>
```

Comment: Multiple controls with SAME name dont affect XHTML rules??

Comment: No, only multiple elements with the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

Use this example, definitely it will help you.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  function runscript()
  {
    document.form1.submit();
    document.form2.submit();
  }
</SCRIPT>
<BODY>
  <FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="http://localhost/login.php" NAME="form1">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="text1">
  </FORM>
  <FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="http://localhost/register.php" NAME="form2">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="text2">
  </FORM>
  <INPUT TYPE="button" value="Submit" onClick="runscript()">
</BODY>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on one of the forms.